# How to connect RS-422 to 2× RS-485?

Tags: arduino, rs485, interface, rs422, connect

I want to connect two Arduinos via RS-422. I have 1 converter RS-422 to TTL and two RS-485 to TTL. How I can connect outputs of my converters (Y,Z,B,A on MAX490 and A,B on MAX485)?

[image]

Comment: Рома Рома - Hi, When a post copies or adapts material (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) from elsewhere, that content must be [correctly referenced](/help/referencing). For online content, the source webpage / PDF / video etc. should be named & linked as a minimum (see the rule about references for offline books / articles). Therefore please [edit] your question to add the appropriate source reference(s) (e.g. source name & link) for that image, and remember to include references in future. (As you are new here, please see the [tour] & [help] as rules here differ from typical forums). TY

Answer (score 0):

RS-422 uses unidirectional connections that are always active. If you want two directions, you need two pairs of signals.
RS-485 used half-duplex, bidirectional connections, i.e., each transceiver must be dynamically configured for sending or receiving.

To configure the first RS-485 transceiver as sender, pull /RE high and DE high. Connect it to the receiver pins (A,B) of the RS-422 transceiver.

To configure the second RS-485 transceiver as receiver, pull /RE low and DE low. Connect it to the driver pins (Y,Z) of the RS-422 transceiver.